# Sequelize Wait until loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I am trying to run sequelize queries and store the values in the array, problem is that when the map is iterating on the element, then it is running all elements at once it is not waiting for the first element queries are finished then new it is running simultaneously.

what's happening to suppose the array is = [0,1,2], when I iterate over it, then all the queries related to the value at array[0], arr[1], array[2]... runs simultaneously.

what I want, when I iterate then all the queries related to value at array[0] gets executed then the loop should run for array[1] values, and so on...

```
  await Promise.all([
            timingBreak.map(async function (element) {
              console.log(
                "**************** STARTING NEW *****************",
                element
              );

              obj.timing_name = element.name;
              obj.start_time = element.start_time;
              obj.end_time = element.end_time;

              //new data points

              var [
                d_total_unique_menu_items_ordered,
              ] = await db.sequelize.query(
                "SELECT count(DISTINCT menui.menu_id) as d_total_unique_menu_items_ordered from ir_reservation_order_menu_items menui join ir_reservation_details_offline booking where booking.restau_id=(:restau_id) and DATE(menui.created_at) between (:from) AND (:to) AND TIME(menui.created_at) >= (:start_time) AND TIME(menui.created_at) <= (:end_time);",
                {
                  replacements: {
                    end_time: element.end_time,
                    start_time: element.start_time,
                    from: from_date,
                    to: to_date,
                    restau_id: restau_id,
                  },
                }
              );

              obj.d_total_unique_menu_items_ordered = await d_total_unique_menu_items_ordered[0]
                .d_total_unique_menu_items_ordered;

              //new data points
              var [
                d_total_number_of_cancelled_menu_items,
              ] = await db.sequelize.query(
                "SELECT count(menui.menu_id) as d_total_number_of_cancelled_menu_items from ir_reservation_order_menu_items menui join ir_reservation_details_offline booking where booking.restau_id=(:restau_id) and menui.is_cancelled=1 AND DATE(menui.created_at) between (:from) AND (:to) AND TIME(menui.created_at) >= (:start_time) AND TIME(menui.created_at) <= (:end_time);",
                {
                  replacements: {
                    end_time: element.end_time,
                    start_time: element.start_time,
                    from: from_date,
                    to: to_date,
                    restau_id: restau_id,
                  },
                }
              );

              obj.d_total_number_of_cancelled_menu_items = await d_total_number_of_cancelled_menu_items[0]
                .d_total_number_of_cancelled_menu_items;

              //new data points
              var [
                d_average_number_of_menu_items_per_order,
              ] = await db.sequelize.query(
                "SELECT (count(distinct menui.ordered_menu_detail_id)/count(distinct menui.ir_order_id)) as d_average_number_of_menu_items_per_order from ir_reservation_order_menu_items menui join ir_reservation_details_offline booking where booking.restau_id=(:restau_id) and menui.is_cancelled=0 AND DATE(menui.created_at) between (:from) AND (:to) AND TIME(menui.created_at) >= (:start_time) AND TIME(menui.created_at) <= (:end_time);",
                {
                  replacements: {
                    end_time: element.end_time,
                    start_time: element.start_time,
                    from: from_date,
                    to: to_date,
                    restau_id: restau_id,
                  },
                }
              );

              obj.d_average_number_of_menu_items_per_order = await d_average_number_of_menu_items_per_order[0]
                .d_average_number_of_menu_items_per_order;

              //new data point
              var [
                d_best_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_pricing,
              ] = await db.sequelize.query(
                "SELECT distinct menui.menu_id,count(menui.menu_id),menui.menu_name,menui.price,sum(menui.price),menui.price_unit_id,sum(menui.quantity) FROM ir_reservation_order_menu_items menui join ir_reservation_details_offline booking where booking.restau_id=(:restau_id) AND menui.is_cancelled=0 AND DATE(menui.created_at) between (:from) AND (:to) AND TIME(menui.created_at) >= (:start_time) AND TIME(menui.created_at) <= (:end_time) group by menui.menu_id order by sum(menui.price) DESC LIMIT 20;",
                {
                  replacements: {
                    end_time: element.end_time,
                    start_time: element.start_time,
                    from: from_date,
                    to: to_date,
                    restau_id: restau_id,
                  },
                }
              );

              obj.d_best_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_pricing = await d_best_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_pricing;

              //new data point
              var [
                d_most_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_quantity,
              ] = await db.sequelize.query(
                "SELECT distinct menui.menu_id,count(menui.menu_id),menui.menu_name,menui.price,sum(menui.price),menui.price_unit_id,sum(menui.quantity) FROM ir_reservation_order_menu_items menui join ir_reservation_details_offline booking where booking.restau_id=(:restau_id) AND menui.is_cancelled=0 AND DATE(menui.created_at) between (:from) AND (:to) AND TIME(menui.created_at) >= (:start_time) AND TIME(menui.created_at) <= (:end_time) group by menui.menu_id order by sum(menui.quantity) DESC LIMIT 20",
                {
                  replacements: {
                    end_time: element.end_time,
                    start_time: element.start_time,
                    from: from_date,
                    to: to_date,
                    restau_id: restau_id,
                  },
                }
              );

              obj.d_most_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_quantity = await d_most_10_selling_menu_items_based_on_quantity;

              timing_based_report.push(obj);
              obj = {};
            }),
          ]).catch((error) => console.log("dynamic data error", error));
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 async function saveData(){
    try {
     for (const id of [1,2,3]) {
         await saveToDb(id);
     }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
 }

 async function saveToDb(id){
    try {
        // use await and apply your logic here
    } catch (error) {
        throw Error("Failed")
    }
 }
```